# C++ Pointers - C - Style Strings

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++

I am fairly new to C++,when I was reading about pointers I got confused a bit:

```
char str[] = "Alex"
char *ptr
ptr = str
cout << ptr
```

This gives "Alex" string itself , rather than the memory location and also, *ptr would give you the letter "A".Would someone explain to me why this is happening please?

Also, in addition to this.When I tried printing 
`cout << *ptr`
it gives me address of 1st character.why is this ?, i was expecting the 1st value instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator<<` has an overload that takes an `ostream` (the type of `cout`) and a `const char*`.

That overload treats the `const char*` argument as a null terminated C-string, and prints characters pointed to by that pointer, until it finds the terminating null character.

Note that passing a `char` pointer that doesn't point to a null terminated sequence of `char`s invokes undefined behavior.

For circumventing this behavior when you simply want to output the memory address, cast the pointer to `void*` first:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(ptr); // outputs the address stored in 'ptr'
```

Comment: would you mind giving me an example with void* casting please ?Also, in usual cases if it is of type say "int", cout << ptr should return a memry address right ?

Comment: @rahul Sure, check the edit. And yes, the char pointer is a special case for compatibility and ease of use with C-style strings. With all other types of pointers the address will be printed. You could technically cast the pointer to something else other than `void*` too, but `void*` is considered the most "neutral" for this purpose.

Comment: Also, in addition to this.When I tried printing cout << *ptr, it gives me address of 1st character.why is this ?, i was expecting the 1st value instead

Comment: @rahul What do you mean by the 1st value? 1st of what?

Comment: sorry, i meant it is just giving a random address .I though I would get value if you deference a pointer

Comment: `cout << *ptr` will print the first character, because that's what `ptr` is pointing to.

Answer (score 2):

C style strings are just C-style arrays of `char`, with all the semantics associated to C-style arrays.

`iostream` is special-cased to behave differently when given a `char` pointer; if you want to print the address you should cast it to `void*` first.

Comment: You won :) I wasn't fast enought ...

Answer (score 2):

it is happen because in c++ you can overload operators,  like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const char* p)
{
    while (*p) cout<<*p++;
}
```

and because char array is a common type of strings, it was done for you in the standard language.

Answer (score 0):

Because strings in C/C++ ends with `'\0'`. The output will run to the next pointer until it reaches the pointer wich point to `'\0'`.

```
ptr + 0 == 'A';
ptr + 1 == 'l';
ptr + 2 == 'e';
ptr + 3 == 'x';
ptr + 4 == '\0'; // stop, end of output
```